# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I am getting an exception, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method.  I understand it is because I use a toList() inside of a Select statement.

```
var study= db.StudySessions.Where(s => s.StudySessionId == sessionId).Select(session => new StudySessionDTO
                {
                    Name = session.Name,
                    TypeCode = session.TypeCode,
                    Tutors = session.Tutors.Select(t => new TutorDTO
                    {
                        FirstName = t.FirstName,
                        LastName = t.LastName


                    }).ToList()

                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I understand it is because I use a toList() inside of a Select statement. However If I remove it, I will get a syntax error.  I must use projection else I will run into a json reference cycle issue when I try to return it.  Any idea how I can fix this issue.

Comment: If you turn off lazy loading you can JSON-serialize entities. Just `Include()` anything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are retrieving a single item, you could force the read into memory by calling `AsEnumerable`, and do the projection after, like this:

```
var study= db.StudySessions
    .Where(s => s.StudySessionId == sessionId)
    .AsEnumerable() // The rest of the query happens in memory
    .Select(session => new StudySessionDTO {
        Name = session.Name
    ,   TypeCode = session.TypeCode
    ,   Tutors = session.Tutors.Select(
            t => new TutorDTO {
                FirstName = t.FirstName
            ,   LastName = t.LastName
            }).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Since the filtering by `sessionId` happens in the database, this will not force all the data into memory.

Comment: Still not the best performance though. `StudySessionId` doesn't look like the primary key on the table so multiple may be returned. Furthermore, for each of those, `Tutors` will need to be queried separately and it'll bring back *all* of the `Tutor` properties instead of the ones that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Project to an anonymous object, *then* project to your DTO:

```
// Simplified to keep some important parts...
var study= db.StudySessions
             .Select(session => new // Anonymous Type
             {
                 Tutors = session.Tutors
                                 .Select(t => new TutorDTO
                                 {
                                     FirstName = t.FirstName
                                 })
             })
             .ToList() // Now it's in memory.
             .Select(session => new StudySessionDTO
             {
                 Tutors = session.Tutors.ToList()
             });
```